# Wifi signing in

Tags: wi-fi

I have android 5 on my mobile . I am using wifi for internet. It should sign in automatically into that wifi network, but it is not doing so. Android is asking me to sign in every time. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Sign in once.
2. While you are doing that, look for 'Remember'. Check that box.
3. Done!

Comment: i have already done that but still facing the same problem.